# count number of days in a month in SAS

Tags: sql, sas

I am looking to get number of days in a month in SAS. The date format I have is yyyymm (e.g.201701) and I would like to record the number of days in a month. The data is recurring on a monthly basis (201701,201702...etc). I have tried to use the Day function along with EOMONTH , however the SAS picks up the SAS date for 201701. I am new to SAS coding and any help would be appreciated.

Comment: This isn't clear at all. What do you have and what do you need? Just that January 2017 has 31 days?  Or is it related to your data somehow? You need to post a lot more information and what you'eve tried. I have no idea what EOMONTH is for example.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SAS date values are numeric type with a value that is the number of days since 1-January-1960.

You need to first understand what type of value your date representing variable is.
Is it:

- character type with digit letters at the meaning place Y Y Y Y M M
- numeric type with date encoded as value 100 * year + month

If EOMONTH is character, you will need to convert it to a SAS date value that includes a day.  For 'month' values that day is usually set to 1.  For example:

```
data _null_;
  myDateString = '201701';
  * note the ||'01' that makes myDate be the first of the month;
  myDate = input (trim(myDateString)||'01', yymmdd8.);
  format myDate yymmd.;
  put myDate=;
  put myDate= 12.; * Show in LOG the date as number of days from reference;
run;
----- LOG -----
myDate=2017-01
myDate=20820
```

Sometimes you will get date representing data which is numeric and encoded to appear like YYYYMM when viewed.  These values also would need to be converted to a SAS date value. For example:

```
data have;
  myDateNumber = 201701;
  * note the , 1 that makes myDate be the first of the month;
  myDate = mdy ( mod(myDateNumber,100), 1, myDateNumber / 100);
  format myDate yymmd.;
  put myDate=;
  put myDate= 12.; * What date value is 'unformatted' is the number of days from reference;
run;
----- LOG -----
myDate=2017-01
myDate=20820
```

There are other ways to convert a character or numeric representation of a date to a SAS date value.  Just be careful to understand that when you are viewing a variable in SAS, you need to know the variable type and the format being applied by the viewer.

Once you have a SAS date value, you can compute the number of days in the month of the date using SAS interval functions INTCK and INTNX.

```
days_in_month = intck ('days', /* how many days between next two args */
  intnx('month', mydate, 0),  /* advance mydate to first of month */
  intnx('month', mydate, 1)   /* advance mydate to first of next month */
);
```

This formula will work regardless of the day of the month of the date value.

Comment: Thanks a lot Richard. My data was a numeric representation and your formula worked for me. Really appreciate your help, while I realised that my question was a bit vague without much info needed !!  You reply was very helpful to understand the logic as well !

Comment: You could also use the `yymmn6.` informat to convert the number to a date.  `myDate=input(put(myDateNumber,6.),yymmn6.);`.  This defaults to the 1st of the month